# Keeping Track of multiple objects that used Matrix Transform C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I posted a question about using Graphics Transform and got a great answer. What I needed was to have a spot on an oval where, if the mouse was in it, the oval would rotate. The code below includes that. However, now I ALSO need a region where, if the mouse is clicked inside it, I can resize the oval.

The problem I'm having isn't with the resize, it's with the region detection because the code that's transforming the resize rectangle isn't working. That same code works great when applied to the small, moving circle, which is leaving me more than a little confused.

When you start out, you have everything correctly placed and working. The oval, the small circle that will rotate it when you click in it, and the green box (Currently hidden under a red one) where if you click in it, you can resize the oval.

[image]

However, if you begin to rotate everything, the red rectangle is what you get. But what I need is that red rectangle to be the exact same size and shape as the green one and in the same place as the green one so that I can use the rectange.Contains(mousepointer) methods.
[image]

I know that I'm missing something basic here, but I have yet to be able to isolate it. Any helpful ideas would be appreciated.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OvalTestV2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int theAngle = 0;
        Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 125, 255), 4);
        Pen pen3 = new Pen(Color.Green, 4);
        Pen smallPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

    bool testspot = false;

    PointF center = new PointF(0, 0);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 30);
    Rectangle myRect2 = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle rotatedRect2 = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle resizeRect = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle resizeRect2 = new Rectangle();
    bool mouseBtnDown = false;
    Graphics gw;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseDown += mouseDown;
        gw = this.CreateGraphics();
    }


    private void mouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (resizeRect.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                testspot = true;
            }
            if (resizeRect2.Contains(e.Location))
                testspot = true;

            if (rotatedRect2.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                gw.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
                theAngle += 5;
                rotate();
            }


        }

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            //oval = false;
            //mouseBtnDown = false;
            theAngle = 0;
            rectangle.X = e.X - 50;
            rectangle.Y = e.Y - 15;
            rectangle.Width = 100;
            rectangle.Height = 30;
            center.X = rectangle.Left + (0.5f * rectangle.Width);
            center.Y = rectangle.Top + (0.5f * rectangle.Height);
            myRect2.Size = new Size(15, 15);
            myRect2.Location = new Point(rectangle.Left - 15, (rectangle.Top - (rectangle.Height / 2)) + 15);

            resizeRect.X = rectangle.X;
            resizeRect.Y = rectangle.Y;
            resizeRect.Size = rectangle.Size;
            rectangle.Location = rectangle.Location;

            rotate();
            //drawstuff();

        }
    }

    public void rotate()
    {
        mouseDnX_lbl.Text = myRect2.X.ToString();
        mouseDnY_lbl.Text = myRect2.Y.ToString();
        var matrix = new Matrix();

        matrix.RotateAt(theAngle, center);
        gw.Transform = matrix;

        //For the Rotation area
        // Get the 4 corner points of myRect2.
         Point p1 = new Point(myRect2.X, myRect2.Y),
          p2 = new Point(myRect2.X + myRect2.Width, myRect2.Y),
          p3 = new Point(myRect2.X, myRect2.Y + myRect2.Height),
          p4 = new Point(myRect2.X + myRect2.Width, myRect2.Y + myRect2.Height);



        Point[] pts = new Point[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 };

        // Rotate the 4 points.
        gw.Transform.TransformPoints(pts);

        // Update rotatedRect2 with those rotated points.
        rotatedRect2.X = pts.Min(pt => pt.X);
        rotatedRect2.Y = pts.Min(pt => pt.Y);
        rotatedRect2.Width = pts.Max(pt => pt.X) - pts.Min(pt => pt.X);
        rotatedRect2.Height = pts.Max(pt => pt.Y) - pts.Min(pt => pt.Y);

        //End of Rotation Area

        //For the Resize area
        Point rp1 = new Point(resizeRect.X, resizeRect.Y),
         rp2 = new Point(resizeRect.X + resizeRect.Width, resizeRect.Y),
         rp3 = new Point(resizeRect.X, resizeRect.Y + resizeRect.Height),
         rp4 = new Point(resizeRect.X + resizeRect.Width, resizeRect.Y + resizeRect.Height);



        Point[] rpts = new Point[] { rp1, rp2, rp3,rp4 };

        // Rotate the 4 points.
        gw.Transform.TransformPoints(rpts);

        // Update rotatedRect2 with those rotated points.
        resizeRect2.X = rpts.Min(pt => pt.X);
        resizeRect2.Y = rpts.Min(pt => pt.Y);
        resizeRect2.Width = rpts.Max(pt => pt.X) - rpts.Min(pt => pt.X);
        resizeRect2.Height = rpts.Max(pt => pt.Y) - rpts.Min(pt => pt.Y);
        //End of Resize area


        drawstuff();
    }

    Pen pen4 = new Pen(Color.Red, 4);

    public void drawstuff()
    {

        gw.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; // Creates smooth lines.
        gw.DrawEllipse(pen2, rectangle);

        gw.DrawEllipse(smallPen, myRect2);
        gw.DrawRectangle(pen3, resizeRect);
        gw.DrawRectangle(pen4, resizeRect2);


    }
```

Comment: Side note: don't do this: `gw = this.CreateGraphics();`  Use the paint event of the container and draw using the supplied graphic object.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add: I can't use the paint event. This is sort of a snippet from code that I'm not allowed to change, and that code doesn't use the paint event. It's... archaic.